# Django - Change Fields in Group Admin Model

Tags: python, django

The built-in django `group` model on the admin site only shows `name`:

[image]

but I want to include additional fields that are already part of the `group` model, such as `id`.

I have tried adding these fields using the following `admin.py` setup:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class GroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "pk"]
    class Meta:
        model = Group

admin.site.register(Group, GroupsAdmin)
```

But this returns the error:

```
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Group is already registered.
```

I have successfully registered other models (I've created) on admin but the above doesn't work for those models that are already a part of django.

How can I add fields in the admin model for `Group`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unregister it first from the built-in `Group` model and then register it again with your custom `GroupAdmin` model.

So:

```
class GroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "pk"]
    class Meta:
        model = Group

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupsAdmin)
```

Also, the `Meta` class is not required. You can remove it.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is correct, however, I would like to point out that you could inherit from the `GroupAdmin` if your goal is only extending that is, and not modifying:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin

class GroupsAdmin(GroupAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "pk"]

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupsAdmin)
```